# Selenium Automation drag and drop functionality issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, automation

I am trying to drag and drop one element but i am not able to release the element at the required position.

The issue is : i want to drop the element in a placeholder that is visible only during runtime (i.e : when i clickAndHold the element and move to the destination element)
After moving to destination element,placeholder is activated where i am supposed to release the element.

Here is my code : (After FirefoxDriver initializations)

```
    String  sourceelement ="#ctl00_ctl44_g_0beb5998_7319_49ac_9956_28684e341659_dvCart img";
    String destinationelement = "#dvZone_LeftColumn";
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(sourceelement)));
    builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(destinationelement)));
    builder.perform();
    Thread.sleep(250);

    WebElement holder = driver.findElement(By.className("placeholder"));
    builder.release(holder).perform();
```

Here is the HTML source snippet (releasing element part) :

"" gets activated under any of the "" depending on where i take that element after dragging.

Issues :

1 - While executing the script ,if i move mouse than the element is released in placeholder so successful execution (but have to move mouse at that time to release the element in placeholder which is not supposed to be done in automation)

2 - If i do not move the mouse,the script fails saying "Cannot find element with classname=placeholder"

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML snippet : 


<div id="dvMainPlaceHolder" class="dragable-container1" style="background-color: transparent;">
     
     <div id="dvZone_LeftColumn" class="sortable-list dragable-div ui-sortable" align="left" style="background-color: transparent;">

     <div id="dvZone_MiddleColumn" class="sortable-list dragable-div ui-sortable" align="left">

     <div id="dvZone_RightColumn" class="sortable-list dragable-div ui-sortable" align="left">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `target` placeholder will be active only when hold the `source` and move the mouse.

What I suggest is that you first click and hold the `source` element and move it by certain offset which will make your target placeholder visible. In this way you can ensure that you don't get  **"Cannot find element with classname=placeholder"** error.

```
        String  sourceelement ="#ctl00_ctl44_g_0beb5998_7319_49ac_9956_28684e341659_dvCart img";
        String destinationelement = "#dvZone_LeftColumn";
        Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
        builder.clickAndHold(_driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(sourceelement)));

        builder.moveByOffset(1, 1).perform();// this will move the mouse by 1,1 which will be holding your source element

        builder.moveToElement(_driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(destinationelement)));
        builder.perform();
        Thread.sleep(250);


        WebElement holder = _driver.findElement(By.className("placeholder"));
        builder.release(holder).perform();
```

Comment: yep, you got my problem right ....i tried the above line of code to move the mouse by offset, but it gives me error : Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (135, 30) 

Any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Try giving some other offset values.

Comment: finally it worked !! I used Robot class to move the mouse in a loop so that the target element is activated during script execution. (used Thread.sleep() to see mouse movement in the required section)